# Como usar o GraphDiff Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas em meu banco de dados:

1. Venda
2. DetalhesVenda
3. ProdutosVenda
4. Parcelas

A relação é a seguinte:

- 1 Venda => N DetalhesVenda
- 1 Venda => N ProdutosVendas
- 1 DetalhesVendas => N Parcelas

Estou tentando fazer o método para adicionar uma nova venda, porém não estou obtendo resultados, o método não dá erro, mas quando vou verificar no banco de dados, o registro não foi gravado.

A seguir tem o código do meu método:

```
public Venda LancamentoVenda(Venda obj)
{
    Db.UpdateGraph(obj, map => map
     .OwnedCollection(d => d.DetalhesVenda, r => r.AssociatedCollection(a => a.Parcelas))
     .OwnedCollection(x => x.ProdutosVendas));
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Faltou Db.SaveChanges();